# Dynamic footer integration

Tags: php, javascript, dynamic

I'ld like to insert the footer of my website dynamically so I can add it to multiply pages without copy and paste it every time. 
I know an iframe can do it but I heard that's not a good solution and not working for seo. 
Can it be done with PHP or JavaScript?

Answer (score 2):

`footer.php` code as follows

```
<?php
//Write your custom footer here
?>
```

`home.php` code as follows

```
<?php

//All contents of Home page

include('footer.php');

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include('path/to/footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP is the right tool for this job:

```
<?php include('footer.php'); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

from php use `include` function

e.g: `<?php include('inc/footer.php');?>`

Comment: Awesome! Thank you guys. If I put my Google Analytics in that footer.php - does it work as in a static page or will it mess up my statistics?